# How to Convert Formated Date string to upper case in EF Core Select statement

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.2, ef-core-3.1

I want to display all the products with manufacture date in the format (DD-MMM-YYYY HH:MM) in the below code I'm getting the date format in lower case. I need to display in upper case (eg 02-FEB-2020 11:43). How to convert to upper case?

```
_dbContext.Product
          .Select(data => new
                          {
                            ProductId = data.ProductId,                  
                            ProductManufactureDate = data.ProductManufactureDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm"),
                          }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this line code

```
ProductManufactureDate=(data.ProductManufactureDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm")).ToUpper(),
```